# how to access and print Binary string type data from DynamoDB using python?

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services

I have put an item in AWS DynamoDB which is in Binary form . I mean my data is encrypted and when I try to access that data to print or assign then I am not able to dousing python

```
import boto3
import base64
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name='us-west-2')
table = dynamodb.Table('xyz')

response = table.get_item(
            Key={
                'id': "2",

            }
        )
item = response['Item']
dec_otp=item['otp']

print(dec_otp) #not able to print  
a=dec_otp      #not able to assign

print(type(dec_otp))
print(item)
```

output:-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "aws_kms3.py", line 23, in <module>
    'name': 'otp'
  File "/home/vinit/Desktop/kms/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 314, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/home/vinit/Desktop/kms/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 586, in _make_api_call
    api_params, operation_model, context=request_context)
  File "/home/vinit/Desktop/kms/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 621, in _convert_to_request_dict
    api_params, operation_model)
  File "/home/vinit/Desktop/kms/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/validate.py", line 291, in serialize_to_request
    raise ParamValidationError(report=report.generate_report())
  File "/home/vinit/Desktop/kms/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/validate.py", line 95, in generate_report
    error_messages.append(self._format_error(error))
  File "/home/vinit/Desktop/kms/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/validate.py", line 112, in _format_error
    ', '.join(additional['valid_types']))
TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type bytes)
```

output2:-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "aws_kms3.py", line 25, in <module>
    CiphertextBlob=bytes(base64.b64decode(dec_otp))
  File "/home/vinit/Desktop/kms/venv/lib/python3.6/base64.py", line 80, in b64decode
    s = _bytes_from_decode_data(s)
  File "/home/vinit/Desktop/kms/venv/lib/python3.6/base64.py", line 46, in _bytes_from_decode_data
    "string, not %r" % s.__class__.__name__) from None
TypeError: argument should be a bytes-like object or ASCII string, not 'Binary'
```

output3:-

```
Binary object is not itterable
```